# open office writer inserted audio file - change and SAVE position and Size settings

Tags: openoffice-writer

I need some help in saving the custom settings of an inserted audio file in a text file in writer.

when the audio file is inserted the width and height are set at 1.97" I need them at 0.16"

The anchor is set to To Paragraph I need it = As Character

Position = center - to - Character

protect = position

all this changes work OK on the selected audio file... but when I insert a new audio file I have to change this settings all over again.
I have to do this for 100s of audio files.

I have look around writer on how to save this custom settings with no luck

I have try to create my own custom menu ... but cant save my custom settings
I try to create a macro... macros do not work from text file to menu recording.
I search the web ... no luck

I hope you can help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This has been Solved !

Comment: If anyone needs the code

Comment: search for:   Position and Size of a inserted audio file in writer    at OpenOffice forums  ... Thanks a lot.